# Copying content from xlsx into notepad using python

Tags: python, excel-2010, text-files, xlsx

I am currently using Excel 2010. I want to parse through all the excel files under a specified path in my system for a specific string (for eg: address).I want to copy all the rows which contain the word address in any of its cells into a notepad.
Should I use openpyxl or pandas? Please help with a basic outline on how I need to go about with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you put some sample data, and expected output that you want?

Comment: you can use pandas if you're familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment so I'm posting as an answer. I used the following code for a very similar application. Hope this is right for you.

**Note: I didn't understand whether you wanted to print an entire row containing keyword 'address' or just the cell containing the keyword. This code is for the latter.**

```
book = open_workbook('Bookl.xlsx')
s=0
for sheet in book.sheets():

    for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
        row = sheet.row(rowidx)
        for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
            if cell.value == 'address':
                address.append(str(sheet.cell(rowidx, colidx)))
                s+=1

f= open("text.txt","w+")
for x in range(0,s):
    f.write(address[x])
f.close()
```

Also for iterating over different excel files in a folder, I don't have much idea. I read online that maybe [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module could help you.

Comment: Was this answer helpful? You haven't replied so maybe it wasn't. Please let me know.

Comment: My requirement changed a little -